# Replacing href value of all <a> and <link> elements

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write two different functions that will replace value of the href attribute. So the first function should replace `href` value of anchor elements, and the second one link `href`. Two functions are required because I want to do different things. So for example for `<a>` href I want to just to prepand some url, and for the `<link>` href I want to prepend different url based on some logic. I've started with this:

```
$pattern = "/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))/";
$response = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'html_href',  $response);
```

That's not really what I want, because `html_href` function won't know where that value of the href came from, and which value to prepend. So would be great if someone could help me write regex patterns, for this style of call, something like this:

```
$pattern_anchor = ""; // ??
$response = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'anchor_href',  $response);

$pattern_link = ""; // ?
$response = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'link_href',  $response);
```

so that those functions just get href value. I'm not really good with regex, and every help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Bad..Bad..Bad.. This is much simpler to do using [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: have you considered using an HTML parser instead?

Comment: Perhaps, regular expressions are not the right tool to use. Have you considered using an XML parser, such as PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)?

Comment: OK, I listened to you guys, but now I have a problem with DOMDocument, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921941/domdocument-and-windows-1250-encoding