# DOMDocument and windows-1250 encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, domdocument

So, I'm writing the code that is supposed to parse different websites, and some of them use `windows-1250` encoding, and some of them use 'utf-8'. I don't have any impact over those websites, and you can probably guess that those pages with 'windows-1250' are giving me headache. So, here's the code that I'm using:

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($response);

        $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
        $anchors = $xpath->query("//a[@href]");
        foreach( $anchors as $anchor) {
            $href = $anchor->getAttribute("href");
            $anchor->setAttribute("href", 'http://example.com/');
        }

        $response = $xpath->document->saveHTML();
```

and here's the output in browser when I try to run this script:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML(): output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x9A 0x61 0x72 0x6B
```

So, is there a way to handle this error with 'windows-1250' encoding, that will work work utf-8 also ? I tried using `utf_encode` with `$response` and that passes, but then international characters are messed up.

Comment: are you sure its `1250`? not `1251 / 1252`?. anyway, can you reproduce this problem

Comment: well, this is directly from the page <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250" />
I'm not sure really why this happens, because some pages work really ok with this encoding, and on some I get this error..

Comment: do you have a live site that can be checked, so we can see whats the problem

Answer (score 0):

if you are just trying to change the href of all of your anchor tags then you could just use jquery

The code would look like this:

```
  //loop through the anchor tags
 $("a").each(function(){//begin each function

  //set the href attributes
  $(this).attr("href","http://example.com/");


  });//end each function
```

Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/fu5fxawm/1/

If you hover over the links you will see that they have been changed.

Comment: I see now it makes sense why you are using php